# Fixed bottom navbar dropup menu drops down into navbar on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, dropdown

### Problem

I am almost finished with my navbar (in code below), but the "Username" dropdown, which drops up on big screens/resolutions (exactly like I want it to), drops down into the navbar for smaller screens. If you run my code and shrink the page, you'll see what I'm talking about. Any solutions for it to drop up (just like it would on bigger screens) when resolution shrinks?

### Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Navbar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
    <style type="text/css">
    body {margin:70px 20px}

    .navbar-nav {
    float: none;
    text-align: center;
    }

    .navbar-nav li {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
    }

    .mrmb {
    margin-right:20px;
    margin-top:-10px;
    }

    .nav-item {
    height:100%;
    width:20%;
    }

    .nav-itemm {
    height:100%;
    width:23%;
    }

    #navigation ul li {
    display: inline;
    padding:50px;
    }

    .inlinee{
    white-space: nowrap;
    }

    .btn-group{
    margin:10px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">          
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item active"><a href="index.html" id="PostsLink">Posts</a><li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="submit.html" id="SubmitPostLink">Submit</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a href="buy.html" id="BuyLink">Buy</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item inlinee"><a href="about_us.html" id="ContactUsLink">About Us</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
        <div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav" style="margin-left:25%; margin-right:-25%;">
                <li class="nav-itemm"><a href="register.html" id="RegisterLink">Register</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown nav-itemm">
                    <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" id="UserControls">Username</a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="view_posts.html" id="ViewPostsLink">View Posts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="change_email.html" id="ChangeEmailLink">Change Email</a></li>
                        <li><a href="change_password.html" id="ChangePasswordLink">Change Password</a></li>
                        <li><a href="log_out.html" id="LogOutLink">Log Out</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance, as this will draw my project to a close if fixed.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Consider adding your markup to a fiddle for better response. http://jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this jsfiddle (click run):
https://jsfiddle.net/q1c1L5y5/

I changed the name of your navbar-nav and nav-item classes to navbar-nav-special and nav-item-special so that they only use your styles and not any other bootstrap styles if they exist.  This seems to work however, when the screen size is small it cuts off the popup to the right.  So you'll need to pad the Username item a little more on the right or find another way.  I'll try to mess with the padding in a bit and if I can get it I'll update this post.  Here's what the updated code looks like from the fiddle:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Navbar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
<style type="text/css">
body {margin:70px 20px}

.navbar-nav-special {
float: none;
text-align: center;
}

.navbar-nav-special li {
float: none;
display: inline-block;
}

.mrmb {
margin-right:20px;
margin-top:-10px;
}

.nav-item-special {
height:100%;
width:20%;
}

.nav-itemm {
height:100%;
width:23%;
}

#navigation ul li {
display: inline;
padding:50px;
}

.inlinee{
white-space: nowrap;
}

.btn-group{
margin:10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<header>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">          
    <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav-special">
            <li class="nav-item-special active"><a href="index.html" id="PostsLink">Posts</a><li>
            <li class="nav-item-special"><a href="submit.html" id="SubmitPostLink">Submit</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item-special"><a href="buy.html" id="BuyLink">Buy</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item-special inlinee"><a href="about_us.html" id="ContactUsLink">About Us</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
    <div>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav-special" style="margin-left:25%; margin-right:-25%;">
            <li class="nav-itemm"><a href="register.html" id="RegisterLink">Register</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown nav-itemm">
                <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" id="UserControls">Username</a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="view_posts.html" id="ViewPostsLink">View Posts</a></li>
                    <li><a href="change_email.html" id="ChangeEmailLink">Change Email</a></li>
                    <li><a href="change_password.html" id="ChangePasswordLink">Change Password</a></li>
                    <li><a href="log_out.html" id="LogOutLink">Log Out</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
</header>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```